# Split without separator with diferent arrays

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, split, strsplit

Could you, please, help me? I need to split a string that doesn't have a separator. I need to split the string in different types.
For example, the following strings should generate the same list as output:

"ak = bib+c*(data+1005)
"

"    ak=    bib +c*    (data +1005 )
"

"                           ak =bib + c * (data + 1005)"

The output should be:

['ak', '=', 'bib', '+', 'c', '*', '(', 'data', '+', '1005', ')']

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `re.findall` with a pattern that matches either a word or a non-space character:

```
import re
re.findall(r'\w+|\S', "ak = bib+c*(data+1005) ")
```

This returns:

```
['ak', '=', 'bib', '+', 'c', '*', '(', 'data', '+', '1005', ')']
```

Comment: So I assume `\w` only uses alpha characters to find a "word"?

Comment: `\w` includes all alphanumeric characters as well as the underscore, which are what typically are considered as valid keyword characters in most programming languages.